# How can I solve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined?

Tags: jquery, laravel-5.3, gulp-watch, summernote, laravel-elixir

I implement summernote in my project

My project use laravel 5.3 & vue.js 2

My javascript code like this :

```
$(function () {
    $('.summernote').summernote({
        height: 200
    });
});
```

I compile my project use laravel-elixir

If I run : `gulp watch` and run my form(the textarea use summernote), it's no error

But if I run : `gulp --production`and run my form(the textarea use summernote), there exist error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

How can I solve the error?

Comment: See link. https://github.com/jackmoore/autosize/issues/322

Comment: @Shree, Okay thanks. It works. I change summernote.min.js with summernote.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error on `autosize.min.js` According to [this](https://github.com/jackmoore/autosize/issues/322) Post
Try:

`autosize.js` instead of `autosize.min.js`.

I post my comment to answer for future reference.